# How can I set the name for a file that is to be downloaded in a Koa response?

Tags: stream, koa

I make a image proxy (to download a image not open) use node and koa.
the url `/proxy/image` code is :

```
...
const PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough
let query = qs.parse(url.parse(ctx.request.url).query)
let passThroughStream = new PassThrough()
ctx.body = request(query.src).pipe(PassThrough())
...
```

The image downloaded name is `image`, but I want to rename the image, how could I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to do this by using `ctx.attachment()` which is an alias for `ctx.response.attachment()`. So you can do something like:

```
ctx.attachment('my-image.png')
```

This `attachment` method is basically a shorthand of the following header:

```
ctx.set('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=my-image.png');
```